# Nothing in query linq

Tags: linq, ef-code-first

I'm trying to translate sql to linq but I get nothing in my query.
My sql:

```
select e.FirstAired, s.SeriesName, e.EpisodeNr, e.SeasonNr
from series s 
join LaastGedownloads l on s.SeriesID = l.SeriesID
join Episodes e on e.SeriesID = l.SeriesID
where e.EpisodeNr = l.LastEpisode
and e.SeasonNr = l.LastSeason
```

My Linq

```
SerieContext sc = new SerieContext();
List<Serie> ds=sc.series.Include("Episodes").Include("LaastGedownload").ToList();
var query = (from s in sc.series
             join l in sc.LaastGedownload on s.SeriesID equals l.SeriesID
             join e in sc.Episodes on l.SeriesID equals e.SeasonID
             where e.EpisodeNr == l.LastEpisode
                   && e.SeasonNr == l.LastSeason
             select s).ToList();
```

[My VS2013 solution zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0277lndbunr3fgs/TheNewSerieDatabase.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When joining episodes you are using `SeasonID` instead of `SeriesID`:

```
join e in sc.Episodes on l.SeriesID equals e.SeasonID
```

But in your SQL

```
join Episodes e on e.SeriesID = l.SeriesID
```

Comment: Oh my mistake. I looked 30 times didn't see it.